# PyQt4: Wait on modeless dialog

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, modeless

Is there a way of waiting on closure of a modeless dialog?

Here is an example application:  I start some program which needs to do some startup stuff and also needs the user to log-in.  Since the user logging in takes some time, I'd like to have the login box be modeless, so that I can continue doing my other startup stuff in the background.  But at some point I am not going to be able to continue until the login process is completed.  So ideally I'd like to be able to call something like `dialog.wait_until_complete()` when I get to that point and have it then act like a modal dialog, only continuing once the user accepts/rejects the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the dialog's [finished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#finished) signal:

```
    self.login.finished.connect(self.handleLoginFinished)
    ...

def handleLoginFinished(self, result):
    if result == QDialog.Accepted:
        # register login...
    else:
        # deal with cancelled login...
```

To prevent user interaction, you could just `hide()` the main window until the login is completed. Otherwise, to change the dialog's modality, you need to do something like:

```
    self.login.hide()
    self.login.setModal(True)
    self.login.show()
```